# Horizontal stretching - group header ListView

Tags: windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

So... Any bright ideas how we can enable Horizontal content stretching on the GroupHeader template of a Grouped ListView in Win RT - phone?

I'm all ears!

I've added a demo application so you can try it out - please do before posting your answer!
Code can be found here https://github.com/Depechie/ListView-HorizontalStretch-RT81

I added 2 pages, MainPage has the problem of not having Horizontal stretching.
MainPage2 has a fix for Horizontal stretching, but because of that fix, the JumpList ( zoomed out view ) is not working anymore.
You can navigate from MainPage to MainPage2 through the appbar button.

Here the 2 visuals

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your fix is overly complicated and deprecated. What you need for your group header style is as simple as the following:

```
<Style x:Key="FixedHeaderContainerStyle"
       TargetType="ListViewBaseHeaderItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

And apply it to your ListView like so (old **ContainerStyle is deprecated** and replaced with HeaderContainerStyle):

```
<GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True"
            HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookGroupHeaderTemplate}"
            HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource FixedHeaderContainerStyle}" />
```

**BUT the header fix wasn't the reason why your ZoomedOutView stopped working**. The issue is because you added the following to MainPage2:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

VirtualizingStackPanel breaks this and the new and improved panel (that includes virtualization is ItemsStackPanel, which is also the default now so **omit this altogether**.

Comment: Yeah I know that the VirtualizationStackPanel was the problem in solution 2 - hence the title about the zoomed out view not working. But thanks for the Style fix!! Tried that route too, but was unawere about where and how to put it!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, add `Width="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualWidth}"` to your `MobileAppsGroupHeaderBorder` on MainPage. That'll render as full width like MainPage2 but the jump list functionality is maintained as normal.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not liking the idea we need to add a 'width' to something in XAML when the framework should know that from itself. HorizontalContentAlignment set to Stretch is the reason why we wouldn't need to set the width...

Comment: @Depechie yeah probably. However, my solution works for the problem you stated.